# Determine OS type in docker

Tags: android, bash, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I want to download an sdk depending on the OS type my docker image is running on. How can I write the below pseudo code in docker script

```
RUN variable x = getOS()
if [ "$x" = "Darwin" ]; then
     RUN wget -q http://xxx/android-ndk-xxxx-darwin-x86_64.bin
else
     RUN wget -q http://xxx/android-ndk-xxxx-linux-x86_64.bin
```

Comment: Do you want to know the OS if the host kernel that is shared with all containers, or the OS if the base image (filesystem) used by an individual container?

Comment: Why would you want a Dockerfile that is dependent on the host os type? That is against the `Build once, Run anywhere` goal of Docker, and probably wont work

Answer (score 4):

Use the `uname` command.

```
x=$(uname)
```

On a darwin system, it should output `Darwin`.

In your dockerfile, the RUN command then could look like this:

```
RUN [ "$(uname)" = Darwin ] && system=darwin || system=linux; \
    wget -q http://xxx/android-ndk-xxxx-${system}-x86_64.bin
```

Or like this (in order to support arbitrary systems):

```
RUN system=$(uname); \
    wget -q http://xxx/android-ndk-xxxx-${system,}-x86_64.bin
```

Comment: One could also avoid touching dockerfile, by passing env var via cli: `docker run -e YOUR_UNAME=$(uname)`